How automate process of creating AD App in ARM Template
I'm trying to automate the process of creating an Azure Enterprise Application.
I've tried to do it first with Deployment scripts, but it seems it's not possible to do this way: Minimal Template to create Azure Enterprise app
Are there any other ways to do it with ARM Template?

This is in public preview

The Azure Resource Manager (ARM) is designed to manage Azure resources. However, Microsoft has decided that all types of user accounts & applications, except managed identities, are fully managed by Azure AD (or Entra ID). While these two systems are integrated, objects managed in Azure AD can be used in Azure (ARM) but still reside in Azure AD. The naming can be quite confusing.
To manage Azure AD resources through code, you can use the Graph API. To create apps, you can follow the instructions described here. The query to create an app is as follows:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications

Body:
{
  "displayName": "Display name"
}

Request Header:

Authentication: Bearer
Content-type: application/json


Microsoft Graph Bicep is currently in PREVIEW, you can check here
Launch VS Code and create two new files, main.bicep and bicepconfig.json in the same folder
bicepconfig.json
{
    "experimentalFeaturesEnabled": {
        "extensibility": true
    }
}

main.bicep
provider microsoftGraph

resource application 'Microsoft.Graph/applications@v1.0' = {
  displayName: 'My application'
  uniqueName: 'my-uniquename'
  appRoles: [
    {
      id: guid('my-uniquename', 'Persons.Read')
      isEnabled: true
      displayName: 'xxxx'
      description: 'xxxxx'
      value: 'Persons.Read'
      allowedMemberTypes: [
        'Application'
      ]
    }
  ]
}


You can refer the application registeration full bicep template here
